# Layout issue regarding 100% height and scrollbar-y

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm having a frustrating issue with not knowing exactly how to layout this correctly, the issue I have is of what I am intending to achieve by having a clean 100% height frame with no overflowing and then having two specific areas that need scrollbar-y and overflow hidden while still being able to have elements below such as the chat controls, and also above such as chat topic.

[Example of Intended Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGGvV.png)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chat Application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="chat-app">

  <!--<div class="top-bar">

    <div class="tools">

      <ul class="tools__menu menu">
        <li class="tools__item menu__item"><a href="#" class="tools__link menu__link">Rooms</a></li>
        <li class="tools__item menu__item"><a href="#" class="tools__link menu__link">Settings</a></li>
        <li class="tools__item menu__item"><a href="#" class="tools__link menu__link">My Profile</a>
          <ul class="tools__dropdown">
            <li class="dropdown__item"><a href="#" class="dropdown__link">Edit My Profile</a>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div> -->

  <div class="chat-body">

    <div class="chat-window">

      <div class="chat-topic">Welcome to General Chat! This is an example topic which can be changed via the moderation options.</div>

      <div class="chat-area">

        <div class="chat-messages">

          <ul class="chat-messages__menu menu">

            <li class="chat-messages__chat-message">
              <div class="chat-messages__avatar"><a href="#" class="chat-messages__link"><img src="assets/img/avatar_0.png" src="Guest" class="user-list__img"></a></div>
              <div class="chat-messages__info">
                <div class="chat-messages__name"><a href="#" class="chat-messages__link">Guest</a> <span class="chat-messages__timestamp">10:00 AM</span></div>
                <div class="chat-messages__message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="chat-messages__chat-message">
              <div class="chat-messages__avatar"><a href="#" class="chat-messages__link"><img src="assets/img/avatar_1.png" src="Guest" class="user-list__img"></a></div>
              <div class="chat-messages__info">
                <div class="chat-messages__name"><a href="#" class="chat-messages__link">Guest</a> <span class="chat-messages__timestamp">10:21 AM</span></div>
                <div class="chat-messages__message">Nunc fringilla sagittis magna, et laoreet dui faucibus ut. Phasellus eu eros tristique.</div>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="chat-messages__chat-message">
              <div class="chat-messages__avatar"><a href="#" class="chat-messages__link"><img src="assets/img/avatar_2.png" src="Guest" class="user-list__img"></a></div>
              <div class="chat-messages__info">
                <div class="chat-messages__name"><a href="#" class="chat-messages__link">Guest</a> <span class="chat-messages__timestamp">10:24 AM</span></div>
                <div class="chat-messages__message">Pellentesque aliquam odio ac consectetur suscipit. Integer euismod varius enim aliquet feugiat. Aliquam dapibus nulla eu lacinia finibus. Donec diam turpis, efficitur eu erat a, commodo malesuada.</div>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="chat-messages__chat-message">
              <div class="chat-messages__avatar"><a href="#" class="chat-messages__link"><img src="assets/img/avatar_3.png" src="Guest" class="user-list__img"></a></div>
              <div class="chat-messages__info">
                <div class="chat-messages__name"><a href="#" class="chat-messages__link">Guest</a> <span class="chat-messages__timestamp">10:24 AM</span></div>
                <div class="chat-messages__message">Pellentesque aliquam odio ac consectetur suscipit.</div>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="chat-footer">

        <form class="chat-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Message" class="chat-form__input">
          <button type="submit" class="chat-form__btn">Send</button>
        </form>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="user-list">

      <div class="user-list__header">

        <div class="user-list__title">Members <span class="user-list__online">5 Online</span></div>

        <div class="user-list__search">

          <form class="search__form">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Username..." class="search__input">
            <button type="submit" class="search__btn"></button>

          </form>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="user-list__body">

        <ul class="user-list__menu menu">

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/avatar_0.png" src="Chat Bot" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status user-list__status--busy" title="Busy"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Chat Bot</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">System Bot</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/avatar_1.png" src="Guest" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Administrator</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/avatar_2.png" src="Guest" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status user-list__status--away" title="Away"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Administrator</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/avatar_3.png" src="Midnight Oil" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Midnight Oil</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Member</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/avatar_4.png" src="Dean Martin" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Dean Martin</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Guest</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/default.png" src="Guest1324" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest1324</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Guest</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/default.png" src="Guest6424" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest6424</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Guest</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/default.png" src="Guest1414" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest1414</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Guest</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/default.png" src="Guest1113" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest1113</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Guest</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/default.png" src="Guest4224" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest4224</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Guest</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/default.png" src="Guest1124" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest1124</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Guest</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="user-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="user-list__link">
              <div class="user-list__avatar"><img src="assets/img/default.png" src="Guest8652" class="user-list__img"><span class="user-list__status" title="Available"></span></div>
              <div class="user-list__info">
                <div class="user-list__name">Guest8652</div>
                <div class="user-list__role">Guest</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: arial;
}

.top-bar {
  background: #333;
}

.chat-app {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu__item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tools {
}

.tools__menu {

}

.tools__item {

}

.tools__link {
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tools__dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.chat-body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.chat-window {
  flex: 5;
  order: 1;
}

.chat-topic {
  background: #333;
  color: #888;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.chat-messages__chat-message {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.chat-messages__avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chat-messages__info {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.chat-messages__name {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.chat-messages__link {
  color: #000;
}

.chat-messages__timestamp {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #bababa;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.chat-messages__message {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.chat-footer {
  padding: 20px;
}

.chat-form {
  position: relative;
}

.chat-form__input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.chat-form__input::placeholder {
  color: #bababa;
}

.chat-form__btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4285f4;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.user-list {
  background: #fff;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px #ddd;
  order: 1;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.user-list__header {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.user-list__title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.user-list__online {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8dc11b;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.search__form {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.search__input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

.search__input::placeholder {
  color: #bababa;
}

.search__btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}

.user-list__body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

.user-list__menu {

}

.user-list__item {

}

.user-list__link {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.user-list__item:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.user-list__avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.user-list__info {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.user-list__name {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.user-list__role {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #bababa;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.user-list__status {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}

.user-list__status:before {
  content: "";
  background: #8dc11b;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.user-list__status--busy:before {
  background: #fc3616;
}

.user-list__status--away:before {
  background: #fcd116;
}
```

What do I need to change to achieve the desired layout? Thanks.

Comment: way to much code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS3 measurements `vw` and `vh` are perfect for full-height layouts, along with the `calc()` propety.

While your current layout is too specific to modify, I'll create a basic one which you can adapt to fit your needs.

The HTML:

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="page-chat">
        <div class="page-chat-topbar"></div>
        <div class="page-chat-box"></div>
        <div class="page-chat-commands"></div>
    </div><!--
 --><div class="page-sidebar">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.page-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.page-chat {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vw - 150px);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.page-chat-topbar {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
}

.page-chat-commands {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #333;
}

.page-chat-box {
     height: calc(100% - 80px);
     overflow-y: auto;
}

.page-sidebar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

This ensures a sidebar on the right, the chat area with a top/bottom bar to fill the remaining space on the left. A fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c5q8pbbk/) to see in action.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.